# Django - This HTTPS site requires a Referer header

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm using Typeform to send a POST request to a Webhook on my server. 
I'm looking at the sample request they give and it doesn't look like they are including a Referer header, so my Django site is blocking their request.

Is there a way to whitelist their domain so that they can keep sending this without the referer?

I know I could use csrf_exempt but that would not be ideal.

I have the domain both in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST.